# Induced homomorphism on $S^1$ non-trivial

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ be a map such that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x\in S^1$. Show that the induced homomorphism $f_\ast:\pi_1(S^1,x_0)\rightarrow\pi_1(S^1,f(x_0))$ is non-trivial.

What I know: 1. a trivial homomorphism maps everything to the identity; in this case $[c_{x_0}]$

2. The induced homomorphism is defined by $f_\ast([\omega])=[f\circ\omega]$
3. $f_\ast$ is trivial iff $f_\ast':\pi_1(X,-x_0)\rightarrow\pi_1(X,-f(x_0))$ is trivial

So what we have is a function which maps antipodal points to antipodal points, and we need to show that the induced homomorphism maps all loops around $x_0$ to the point $f(x_0)$. I started my attempt with a proof by contradiction, but I wasn't sure where the contradiction would come in.

Comment: Arguing by contradiction is not a good strategy for this proof. To prove a group homomorphism $g : G \to H$ is non-trivial, you must prove the existence of an element of $G$ whose $g$-image is not the identity.

Comment: Do you know how to characterize when $f_*$ is trivial in terms of the lift of $f$ to a path in the universal cover of $S^1$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I know what the lift of a path is, but I'm not sure how that transfers to this case.